# MongoDB Compass Error - Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I am trying to run the following query on MongoDB Compass but encountered Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found error. I used the template provided for $geoNear but unable to get pass the error.

```
    /**
 * options: The geo query options.
 */
{
  near: {type : "Point", coordinates : [ -153.00, 58.00 ]},
  distanceField: "coordinates",
  maxDistance: 500000,
  query: Limits results that match the query
  includeLocs: Optional. Labels and includes the point used to match the document.
  num: Optional. The maximum number of documents to return.
  spherical: true
}
```

Comment: Can you post complete query?

Comment: Aggregate expects its first argument to be an array, not an object.  Try putting that `$near` stage inside of `[]`